# I paste image inside the drawable folder in android studio 4.1 , it shows red lines (error line) in image name

Tags: android, drawable

This is my project folder, when i adding first image then it not show any error but after adding the 2nd and 3rd image it show the red lines.
I don't know where i do mistake, if anyone knows then please help me.

[image]

Comment: below that image name - eye1.png and eye2.png

Comment: I see seven red lines.  But.. can you compile and run your app?

Comment: Can you try to reopen your project and/or invalidate the cache? If you hover of the files, did you get any error message?

Comment: there is no compilation error or run time error app is installing successfully

Comment: I close my android studio also but still showing red lines.

Comment: Now i close the android studio then shut down the Laptop , now it's fine , thank you

Comment: invalidate cache and restart android studio.

Answer (score 11):

In Android Studio, click on View > Tool Windows > Resource Manager in the menus or click on the Resource Manager tab to the left of the Project window.
Click the + below Resource Manager, and select Import Drawables. This opens a file browser.

Comment: This was my issue. You can't just copy them into the folder. You have to "import" them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the name of the image you are trying to add does not resemble some keyword. I was trying to add an image in drawable with name "try". When i made it "tried" error went away. So, name your image != any keyword.

**FOR YOUR CASE IN PARTICULAR:**

Try invalidating cache and restarting it. Moreover, also check if the problem persists only with these two images or others too.

Comment: eye is not a keyword

Answer (score 2):

Names should be in lowercase.
Therefore never use names with uppercase letters in it

Answer (score 0):

try removing numerals and keep a meaningful name. Also ensure that the names are in lower case

Answer (score 0):

drawable folder is **wrong** place for `png` files.
In drawable are stored `xml` files

All `png` files should be stored in `mipmap` folders

If you want have only one png for all resolutions, store it in `mipmap-anydpi`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
Add the same image to the default drawable folder. Android Studio automatically doesn't add it to the default drawable folder.

Answer (score -2):

It usually happen because of the name assigned to image file. try to put the name of file in **snake_case**.[error][solution]

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9c1v.png)C.png[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naqpa.png)